# Submenus in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I know you can create pages under a parent eg:

```
-a
--c
--d
--e
-b
--f
--g
```

But all of the themes I've looked at will only display the top menus.

```
-a
-b
```

How can I create a menu with drop downs for the sub menus I'll handle the drop down scripting, but how do I access the page names in order to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **depth** argument in the `wp_list_pages` template tag
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages